# Changing python interpreter windows

Tags: python, windows

I have two python installations, 2.5 and 2.6
I want to change the default python interpreter from 2.5 to 2.6.
Anyone know how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PYTHONPATH is **NOT** what you are looking for. That is for varying where Python's "import" looks for packages and modules.

You need to change the **PATH** variable in your environment so that it contains e.g. "....;c:\python26;...." instead of "....;c:\python25;....". Click on start > control panel > system > advanced > environment variables. Select "path". Edit it. Click on OK enough times to get out of there.

Comment: I know, but on his link there is a topic about the path so I just edited it and now everything is working. Sorry but he answered first

Comment: Note that this won't change file extension associations. For those, see http://superuser.com/questions/310335/how-do-i-change-the-file-association-to-a-program-with-the-same-name-in-windows/1052785#1052785

Answer (score 1):

just FYI, since both c:\python25 and c:\python26 are on PATH, I copy C:\Python25\python.exe to C:\Python25\py25.exe, and copy C:\Python26\python.exe to C:\Python26\py26.exe
Then just type py25(or py26) get the specific version.