# Change default Python interpreter on Windows XP

Tags: python, django, version

I have two python versions: Python 2.5 and Python 2.7. When I'm setting up django, I want to use Python 2.7, but django is using Python 2.5 somehow.

How can I make sure that django use Python 2.7? I'm using Windows XP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing python interpreter windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053794/changing-python-interpreter-windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your PATH system environment variable to point to the version of Python you want to use.

Comment: Note that this won't change file extension associations.

Answer (score 21):

Changing your PATH will help, if you always call python directly, rather than relying on 
file association.

For example: `"python foo.py"` will run the 'foo' script with whichever python is first on your PATH.

However, if you just run `"foo.py"`, the handler associated in the registry, for this file extension, will be the first one called.

In your case, it sounds like that would be python 2.5.  Have a look by opening regedit, and checking the
values of:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command
```

The (default) value listed will probably be something like `"C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*`

A quick (and dirty?) fix for you would be to change these values to the python version you actually want.

A better fix would be to do something like what's outlined in this feature request:

http://bugs.python.org/issue4485

Since then, as long as you had admin rights, you could switch as you needed by pointing assoc at the version you want quickly.

Comment: BTW Quick way to find out handler for python file extension: `ftype|find /I "python"`

Comment: this answer provides more details on finding what is associated with .py http://stackoverflow.com/a/5088548/264607 and shitalshah answer is more current: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24277570/264607

Answer (score 12):

Make two simple .cmd files:

python25.cmd:

```
@echo off
set PYTHONHOME=c:\python25
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\python25
```

python27.cmd:

```
@echo off
set PYTHONHOME=c:\python27
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\python27
```

Now you can switch between Python 2.5 and 2.7. :)

Answer (score 5):

Python installer does no change to PATH environment variable under windows.
When typing something like `python setup.py` windows first looks for python in PATH, then in current user registry hive

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe
```

and then in local machine registry hive

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe
```

Answer (score 5):

Now that Python 3.3 is released it is easiest to use the py.exe utility described here:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/

It allows you to specify a Python version in your script file using a UNIX style directive.  There are also command line and environment variable options for controlling which version of Python is run.

The easiest way to get this utility is to install Python 3.3 or later.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to switch between Python 2.x and Python 3.x then easiest way is to use [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) which is included since 3.3 version. This is basically py.exe in Windows folder. To start Python 3.x command prompt, just type

```
py -3
```

To execute script with Python 3.x, use

```
py -3 script.py
```

If you don't specify -3 then 2.x version is used by default. You can also make this explicit by using -2.7 switch.

```
py -2.7 script.py
```

Finally, you can now embed the version number to use in .script file itself. This works because after Python 3.3+ is installed, it associated py.exe with .py files.

```
#! python3
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))
```

Comment: I would add that you can change the default in py.ini file included in the location of py.exe

Answer (score 1):

Change the registry key at

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command
```