# is there any way to switch between python 2.7 and 3.4 in cmd (windows 10)?

Tags: python

I need help to switch between python 2.7 and 3.4 in windows 10 command prompt.
I have installed both version but by default python 2.7 is selected.
Need some command in cmd which help to switch between versions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-default-python-version

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the path of the versions explicitly:

```
> C:\Python27\python
```

or

```
> C:\Python34\python
```

Comment: i tried but its not working even i go to python34 its still enter into 2.7

Comment: And how do you know it's 2.7?

Comment: c:\Python34>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: See if the path to your Python3 is included in the `PATH` environment variable. In any case , you can search for `Python 3.4` in windows search to use the command line of Python 3 dierectly

Comment: thanks it worked but what i need is as i am working in different directory;in that directory can i change between versions ?

Comment: You should be able to change, if you're in the main cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to use `virtualenv`

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

It helps you by managing/switching between several virtual Python environments.