# Error with npm install - a pre-gyp error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I wanted to install [this](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular2-calendar#installation) angular 2 calendar using npm. Tried to use npm to install it and then downloaded it and tried to install it. In both cases its failed.

I am on windows and I previously got this error trying to install angular2 CLI. Now I am getting the same error for this package and I am not sure how to rectify it. I tried to unistall the CLI and then clear the cache and that didnt work.

Could some one have a look at the error and let me know what steps I need to do to rectify this..

The error as it appears on the cmd is as follows:

```
        C:\Users\simon\SPA\ANGULAR2 CALENDAR EXAMPLE>npm install

    > node-zopfli@1.4.0 install C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli
    > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

    node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@6.6.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error
     MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
    ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\simon\
    node_modules\node-zopfli\build\zopfli.vcxproj]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-zopfli\\lib\\binding\\node-v48-win32-x64\\zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-zopfli\\lib\\binding\\node-v48-win32-x64"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli
    gyp ERR! node -v v6.6.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.6.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
```

I am on node.js 6.6.0 and npm 3.10.3

**EDIT:**

I was hoping Luiz answer...

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

would work but unfortunately, whist the install worked perfectly for gym.. I got these errors.. as follows...

```
    > node-zopfli@1.4.0 install C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@6.6.0 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and select
ing "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\build\zopfli.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-zopfli\\lib\\binding\\node-v48-win32-x64\\zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-zopfli\\lib\\binding\\node-v48-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli
gyp ERR! node -v v6.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\simon\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\simon\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64' (1)
npm WARN install:node-zopfli@1.4.0 node-zopfli@1.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN install:node-zopfli@1.4.0 Exit status 1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\simon\package.json'
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN string-replace-loader@1.0.4 requires a peer of webpack@1.x.x || 2.x.x || 2.x.x-beta but none was installed.
npm WARN simon No description
npm WARN simon No repository field.
npm WARN simon No README data
npm WARN simon No license field.
```

There appears to be more issues.. any more ideas

Comment: Hey I updated my my answer. i forgot to mention a step i did prior to installing [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had a similar problem on windows, installing node-gyp globally removed those errors.

```
# before installing node-gyp on windows
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

# install node-gyp globally
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: I got this on yet another project I wanted to install and on that one I got failed dependencies on fsevents "npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:" However windows tools installed (I have noted that python 2.7 is a new installation on my system) as did node-gyp and finally I got the node_modules folder to be created and I was able to run the app.  I still cant install cli though... added +1 for Luiz

Answer (score 28):

Remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`. Run `npm install`

Comment: It worked! Very common but not avoidable 

Answer (score 12):

Using mac os, Running this command helped.

```
npm --build-from-source install node-pre-gyp
```

Comment: worked on windows for me too :D

Answer (score 6):

I had to install python first python.org, you need to use version 2.7 as node-gyp doesn't support the later versions.

So install python 2.7, then `npm install -g node-gyp`.  That worked for me and got rid of all the other errors install angular-cli as well.

Answer (score 6):

#### Use an older version of node

What worked for me was to use an older version of node.

For example, I was using node `v14` and using `v12` completed the instalation.

To do that, you should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569481/11322237).

#### If not enough use an older python version

If using an older version of node is not enough, then you should also use and older python version.

For example, I was using python `v 3.9` and changing to using `v 2.7` solved it.

To do that, you should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913040/11322237).

Comment: Only answer that worked for me without admin permissions on Windows

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error when I was running a project which has `sqlite3` package and It seems like the one causing error when I run `npm install`. So, I resoved this by:

1. Removing the sqlite3 in package.json
2. Running `npm install`
3. Reinstalling sqlite3, `npm install sqlite3`

Comment: Thank you so much bro you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by typing the following:

```
 npm install grpc --save
 npm install node-pre-gyp --save
```

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a problem with proxy. So I set an invalid npm proxy value in npm config. Then i got following output:

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN download ignoring invalid "proxy" config setting: "0.0.0.0"
[bcrypt] Success: ...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was updating Node to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked,

1. Download the package from git (https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) as zip
2. Extract the zip
3. npm install --build-from-source --sqlite=/path/to/extracted/folder

Refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#building-from-the-source

Answer (score 0):

**I am also getting similar error**

when trying to install **bycrpt** which have a dependencies on [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

[image: Image Error]

inside the installation guideline [Bycrpt](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js)
I found the the solution of error which say's

`node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz`

I did follow the guideline and resolve this error (which cause due to dependencies)

**##SIMPLE SOLUTION##**

I changed the version of `bycrpt` from `1.0.3` to `5.0.1`

[image: Byrcpt version]

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me. For Chinese developer, create `.npmrc` file, and add:

`node-pre-gyp=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-pre-gyp`

Answer (score 0):

If you have bcrypt installed, you can remove or find another lib with the same functionality, its one of the cause of this error

Answer (score -2):

I was facing this issue now, after some dynamic setup it's work as below

1. use bash command in your terminal (zsh is not working good here)
2. type: nvm install 12.18.2
3. type: nvm use 12.18.2
4. npm install
5. npm start
6. (Bingo...)

Answer (score -3):

Just need to downgrade node to 10, then it works well.

```
sudo n 10.16.0
```

and DONE!