# having problem to install bcrypt with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, bcrypt

I'm unable to install bcrypt using npm on my windows because I encounter the following errors.

and i also tried these commands but none of these worked

`npm install --save bcryptjs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt`

`npm install -g node-gyp`

`npm install --g --production windows-build-tools`
then

`npm install bcrypt`

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'D:\Programs\NodeJs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=F:\Web dev projects\FusionReact\fusion_backend\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=F:\Web dev projects\FusionReact\fusion_backend\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)     
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (F:\Web dev projects\FusionReact\fusion_backend\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)       
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)  
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "D:\\Programs\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "F:\\Web dev projects\\FusionReact\\fusion_backend\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd F:\Web dev projects\FusionReact\fusion_backend\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v20.5.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: `bcryptjs` should work without any problem

Comment: I don't have Windows here to test, but I think you need a Unix-compatible shell (like bash or zsh) to have the `&&` operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with npm install - a pre-gyp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674390/error-with-npm-install-a-pre-gyp-error)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your node version to 18.19.1 using nvm

```
nvm install 18.19.1
```

And then enter

```
nvm use 18.19.1
```

After that install bcrypt using npm

```
npm i bcrypt
```

That worked for me

If nvm is not installed then checkout this repo [nvm installation guide](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#readme)

verify nvm installation using

```
nvm -v
```