# error: command 'C:\\ Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, pip

Hi so I was trying to `pip install python-ldap` using my git bash but at first it told me that i don't have `cl.exe` so i downloaded the visual studio C++ pack now it's showing this error

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I never coded with C++ so I'm not sure what the error is. I downloaded the CLI tools for C++ too and I don't think it's because the `cl.exe` isn't in the path since it found it. Any insights ??

Comment: For me I didn't have the SDK installed when installing the C++ tools. Installing it from the C++ build tools fixed this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a valid solution for this error but one workaround is to install the windows binary package from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap

Comment: Is it safe to install the unofficial windows library

Answer (score 11):

I know this question was asked years ago, but for future users, I thought of providing an answer for this question. Today I've faced the same problem with the "Microsoft visual studio 2019 build tool."

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have come across this issue while trying to install the dependency through anaconda3 cmd in windows OS.

```
pip install sparse_dot_topn
```

I have tried different methods suggest in different portals and couldn't resolve this for hours. At the same time, I've ended up installing unnecessary components of the visual studio build tool as well. Finally, I found the problem is associated with the setup tool library, and the problem can be solved through force upgrade to the setup tool package

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 9):

Install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126 with default selection.

Comment: thank you sooo much. I had been at the point where I was about to lose all my home

Comment: didn't work for me, same error even after restarting

Comment: if you can provide your pc specs and windows version details, may be I can point you towards something more concrete

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue. I was trying to build pandas from source. I figured out that my build tools were not compatible with the source. I had MSVC v142 installed. So I installed the below components and this worked for me:

- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.0)
- MSVC v141 - VS 2017 C++x64/x86 build tools

These tools can also be installed from cmd, just install visual studio 2019 build tools exe and then run this command in cmd as admin:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache ^
--installPath C:\BuildTools ^
--add "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools;includeRecommended" ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141 ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64 ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763
```

I also had to install additional tools to make it work correctly:

- C++/CLI Support for v141 build tools (14.16)

Once the tools were installed correctly then I had to initialize x64 environment with new installed build tools:

```
"C:\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16 10.0.17763.0
```

After that I restarted my computer and build pandas again and it was build successfully.

Comment: well this is the one that worked for me, i think the key was C++/CLI support.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to copy or link (using [link shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html)) the x64 version of "C Connector" to the x86 folder.

#### If you can't find the x64 C connector...

1. Download `mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.12.0.msi` from their website:
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/
2. Run the Installer, and click the `Add` button on the right, then locate the `Connector C 6.1 x64`

The C++ Connector has C compatible header files, but hard-linking to it does not work, as explained here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

You cannot install the x86 version alongside the x64 version. The installer does not permit this.

#### Otherwise, Hard-Link the x64 version

1. Install [link shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html).
2. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\MySQL\" then right click on "MySQL Connector C 6.1" and click `Pick Link Source`
3. Navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\" and `Drop Link As...` > `Junction`

   - A Junction is a duplicate reference in the file system to a folder. Creating a second junction reclassifies the original folder a junction as well, but they are both authentic references to the same folder, and so, unlike symbolic links, they will work with scripts, because they are real, and are implemented on the file system level.
4. Then, if the connector you have installed is a different version number and you want to try to force it to work with a non-compatible script, rename it to match the folder mentioned in the error message. For example...

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726
     \bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 "-I **`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1`** \include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-Ic:\program files\python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visu...

Crappy pip code failing to pass variables from the system environment :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I had installed a 32-bit python interpreter from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ mistakenly in my 64-bit windows machine.

Then I downloaded the correct 64-bit interpreter setup and installed it. Then I pointed the Pycharm interpreter path to it.

Then my issue was solved. I hope this will help you...

Comment: I've the same issue:
-  src/spt_setup.c(23): warning C4273: '__p__environ' 
but I've Python 64bit:
- Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
and I've
- Visual Studio Builds tools 2019
with MS Visual C++ 2013, 2015-2019
On Windows 10Pro x64.

Answer (score 0):

When I was perusing the internet to find the solution I ran into an adjacent problem:
[Python was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348890/python-was-not-found-run-without-arguments-to-install-from-the-microsoft-store), which I solved by (assuming your python works and is added to PATH) going to **Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases** and turning off "python". They try installing your package again

Answer (score 0):

Install the C++ build tools from here: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads

Search for 'build tools' and download the latest VS build tools installer. Install the C++ build tools (currently it's called "Desktop Development with C++") with the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in the same situation: Except installing VS Build Tools, install whole Visual Studio. Python libs often require C/C++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error; although when installing `lux-api`

What worked for me was downgrading the default python version 3.10 -> 3.9
([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-default-python-version-in-windows))

p.s. the error that I had was the following

```
  error: command ...\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command

```
pip install ldap3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

1. Go [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).
2. Scroll down and search for "Visual Studio Build Tools 2022" (see image)
   [image]
3. Run the downloaded app and Install "Desktop development with C++". I also installed some individual packages in the "Individual components" tab but I am not sure if it is needed or not (try it). In any case, to the right of the image you have the packages I installed.
   [image]