# AWS CLI in Windows is giving blank output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS and trying to setup my CLI in Windows 10.
My cli version is : aws-cli/2.1.19 Python/3.7.9 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

I was able to complete 'aws configure' but when i run 'aws iam list-users' I do not get any results.
If it helps, the 'last used' for my accesskeyID is also not updating (still N/A).

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "when i run 'aws iam list-users' I do not get any results"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
When I write 'aws iam list-users' on CLI, I get a blank line as output. I have one user set up in IAM so I should at least get that. When I run the same command on the AWS CloudShell, I get the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is old issue however this can be help  some one

1)check have  you installed python, if it is not install python and [set Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348890/python-was-not-found-run-without-arguments-to-install-from-the-microsoft-store)

2)Uninstall previously installed [AWS CLI and reinstall again](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html)