# Python Module not found despite being installed

Tags: python, macos, pandoc

I am trying to tell pandoc to use a custom pandocfilter written in python. I am on a MacBook M1 and therefore there is a 2.7 and a homebrewed 3.9.7 version of python installed.

For some reason the pandocfilter module is not found despite being installed correctly.

This is the script I'm trying to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str
import re

def replace(key, value, format, meta):
    if key == 'Str':
        if '[[' in value:
            new_value = value.replace('[[', '')
            return Str(new_value)
        if ']]' in value:
            new_value = value.replace(']]', '')
            return Str(new_value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJSONFilter(replace)
```

`/usr/bin/env python3` points to the correct python version so I have no clue where the issue may be.

I'm looking forward for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Python not found' despite having been installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66408996/python-not-found-despite-having-been-installed)

Comment: No, the issue is not that python is not found but a module