# Python not found on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have Python on my PATH but when I run the command prompt `python --version` I got:

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Any help with Windows would be appreciated...

Comment: What does `py --version` say?

Comment: Python 3.x might be aliased to `python3` depending on your installation process

Comment: @MustafaAydın I don't even know what that means sorry. My ADMIN installed Python from the website and clicked `add to PATH` for me...

Comment: I meant can you run `py --version` command instead of `python --version`.

Comment: From where you downloaded the python. Microsoft Store or from their website

Comment: I suggest you to download python from this site. https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: That is a link to a web page to persuade you to download Python from the Microsoft Store. But most people will recommend that you get it from python.org instead.

Comment: This answer might helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496777/6280135 Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to download python from https://www.python.org/. During installation be sure to check the install to path option.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has made it easier for non-professionals to install Python as of their 10 May 2019 update. See [Who put Python in the Windows 10 May 2019 Update?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/) for more details why this is done. As a result, you get this strange error when you try to run Python, even if you have installed it officially from [the official Python download site](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

The solution to this problem is perfectly described in this other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348890/python-was-not-found-run-without-arguments-to-install-from-the-microsoft-store).

Answer (score 0):

I think your cmd prompt path and python path is not in same location.

First check the python location on your PC.

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

If it is on D: or another location you have 2 options, you can delete and re-install python to C: or you can open cmd prompt from D: or related python path.