# python has been installed (could be show in cmd) but can not run py file?

Tags: python

[image: Picture about the problem]

I am newbie with python and here is my problem. I installed python on my windows pc and as you can see on this picture, I checked it by the command `python --version` and it showed me the version, no problem.

But when I ran this very simple code:

```
my_text = "We made it!"
print(my_text)
```

It said to me that Python was not found! as you can see in the picture.
I searched on the internet, and add the path variable as they said in this guide:
[Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348890/python-was-not-found-run-without-arguments-to-install-from-the-microsoft-store)
but it still does not run.

Could you please give me some advise on how to solve this?

Comment: First you run *python* then you run *python3*.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try running the program in python's official ide

Answer (score -1):

Try using `python` to run your `.py` file, like this

```
python test.py
```

If you are seeing instructions that say to use `python3` to run Python scripts, it's probably because the author of those instructions uses a system environment where `python` is used for Python 2 and `python3` is used for Python 3.

In your case on Windows, Python 3 was almost certainly installed using `python` as the command to run, so you should use `python` and not `python3` to run your scripts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide much of an answer to the question. At best your post might be a helpful comment, however you [can't do that yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post.