# Python not found. cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I get a message saying Python was not found.

This is a part of my code

```
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-u', action="store")
parser.add_option('-d', action="store")
parser.add_option('-t', action="store")
options, args = parser.parse_args()

readerID = str(options.u)
docID = str(options.d)
task_selection = str(options.t)

if task_selection == '2a':
    print("Countries of Visitors:")
    for k,v in (Counter(program.ViewByCountry(docID,task_selection))).items():
        print(k,"-->",v)
elif task_selection == '2b':
    print("Continents of Visitors:")
    for k,v in (Counter(program.ViewByCountry(docID,task_selection))).items():
        print (k,"-->",v)
```

This is my task.

Provide a command-line interface to test your program like this :

```
% cw2 -u user_uuid -d doc_uuid -t task_id -f file_name
```

When I put this in  my command line :

```
python3 cw2.py -d 140218233015-c848da298ed6d38b98e18a85731a83f4 -t 3a
```

I get a message saying Python was not found.
I have created this in Pycharm.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Show the _exact_ error message, not just a summary of its text.

Comment: If it's saying that `python3` isn't in your path, that's something we need to know.

Comment: (also, what platform are you on? If this is Windows, then instead of `python3`, you might need to run `py -3`).

Comment: I created my program in pycharm. I don't get the error message now. I installed python and now I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3 cw2.py -t 4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 cw2.py -t 4
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's because you need to run it at a _shell_ prompt, but you're instead running it at a _Python_ prompt.

Comment: cmd right? I tried it through cmd

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65348890

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348890/python-was-not-found-run-without-arguments-to-install-from-the-microsoft-store)

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't added python to path.
This question is most probably a duplicate you might want to search stackoverflow before asking a new question later on.

first press windows key and search python.

then right-click on python and choose open containing folder

from there copy the address of python.exe executable

add the copied address to path

To add to path:
https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/

PS: i dont think you need to specify the '3' at the end of the command (eg: python3) that is usually for linux users on windows just make sure you have the latest version and type:

`python *filename* [flags]`

Comment: Python-on-Windows has a `py` launcher that's the official Right Way to find the correct Python executable, even if multiple interpreters are installed (it's common to have both a Python 3 interpreter and a Python 2 interpreter so one can work on projects targeting both major revisions of the language). This answer would be stronger if it described how to use it.