# Error when installing fbprophet on windows 10 using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, facebook-prophet

I try to install "*fbprophet*" on Windows 10, using the following command:

```
pip install fbprophet
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: Command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DBOOST_NO_DECLTYPE -DBOOST_PHOENIX_NO_VARIADIC_EXPRESSION -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 -DFUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE=12 -I.\pystan -Ipystan/stan/src -Ipystan/stan/lib/stan_math/ -Ipystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.3 -Ipystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0 -Ipystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/sundials_4.1.0/include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\python39\V_3.9.8\soft\WPy64\python-3.9.8.amd64\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\python39\V_3.9.8\soft\WPy64\python-3.9.8.amd64\Include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include /EHsc /Tppystan/_api.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\pystan\_api.obj /EHsc -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB /std:c++14" failed with exit status 2
```

Any help is priceless !

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: command 'C:\\ Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494411/error-command-c-visual-studio-2017-community-vc-tools-msvc-14-14-2642)

Comment: No, I installed C++ but I still have the same error.