# Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 MSVC 14.36.32532 cl.exe failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, visual-c++, openmmlab

I'm trying to reproduce a [table recognition GitHub project](https://github.com/DevashishPrasad/CascadeTabNet).
Environment: Win11 with Python 3.8, PyTorch 1.4.0, torchvision 0.5.0, and running on CPU only.
I encountered an issue while installing mmcv; the compilation keeps failing with the error:

```
d:\academic\internship\python\lib\site-packages\torch\include\ATen/core/TensorMethods.h(1417): note: 参见“at::Tensor::index”的声明
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(40): note: 尝试匹配参数列表“(initializer list)”时        
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(41): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(41): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(42): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(42): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(44): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(44): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(45): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(45): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(45): error C2664: “at::Tensor at::Tensor::index(at::TensorList) const”: 无法将参数 1 从“initializer list”转换为“at::TensorList”
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(45): note: 无构造函数可以接受源类型，或构造函数重载决策不明确
      d:\academic\internship\python\lib\site-packages\torch\include\ATen/core/TensorMethods.h(1417): note: 参见“at::Tensor::index”的声明
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(45): note: 尝试匹配参数列表“(initializer list)”时        
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(46): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(46): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(47): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(47): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(49): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(49): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(49): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(51): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(51): error C3861: “Slice”: 找不到标识符
      ./mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/cpu\bbox_overlaps_cpu.cpp(51): error C2065: “None”: 未声明的标识符
      error: command 'D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mmcv
  Running setup.py clean for mmcv
Failed to build mmcv
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mmcv, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried all the solutions mentioned in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494411/error-command-c-visual-studio-2017-community-vc-tools-msvc-14-14-2642), but none of them seem to work.
Please provide me with some advice or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: try installing with ```pip install mmcv==VERSION_NUM``` where ```VERSION_NUM``` is the exact version number you need to install.  This sometimes resolves theissue.

Comment: thank you very much. I've installed mmcv-full instead, and it worked!