# How to set python 3.x priority?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.8, python-3.7

So, I have two python versions: 3.7.4 and 3.8.0 . After I installed python 3.8, I wanted to shift to 3.8 without deleting 3.7.4, but whenever I use python, 3.7.4 shows up, and it won't use 3.8 ; unless I type in the terminal: "python3.8", but when I want to use Django(Django is installed in both), or something else, python 3.7.4 shows up. It's gotten fixed when I deleted 3.7.4 , but later when I installed anaconda, this again showed up. I tried many things via advanced system settings' Environment variables(I use windows 10), but no luck. Any suggestions?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YITsA.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fx15.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDF5a.png

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-the-default-python-version-in-windows

Comment: No, it didn't work, I actually have tried it.