# Change the version of Python that runs by default

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit

I have two versions of python installed in my pc:

[image]

and:

[image]

when I type in cmd 'python', the version executed is 3.7.1 32 bits, and all my projects run on that version, which caused me problems when trying to install the pyarrow library. I would like my projects to run on the 64-bit version. Is it possible to change the default versions on which I run python? I cannot delete the 32-bit version, as I do not have administrator access.

Comment: Have you added the 64 bit versiomn into the PATH and removed the 32 bit version?

Comment: how do I do that? I'm a linux user, I have little practice on windows

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57334281/9050514