# Unable to run python file from terminal

Tags: python

I usually use `PyCharm` but, i was trying to run `py` extension file from terminal.

[image]

I have already installed `opencv-python`. [image]

I tried `pip3 install opencv-python` also. Nonetheless, I am having the same issue. But, I am able to run those files from `PyCharm`.

Comment: please try `python3 paint.py`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia solved!!! :) <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be due to the fact that the terminal is using `python2` version by default and you need to explicitly specify `python3` while running the program to use `python3`.

You can see the link [How Should I Set Default Python Version In Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-default-python-version-in-windows) to set your default python version to `python3` in Windows.