# pynacl module installed but not found

Tags: python, pynacl

Edit: Found a fix (see at the bottom)

So my problem is very similar to this one [I cant import pynacl module. (discrod.py - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynacl')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222729/i-cant-import-pynacl-module-discrod-py-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named)

In fact I encountered exactly the same thing basically, now the thing is, wherever I searched, the fixes proposed implied either using a python/python3 prompt command, or go check something in AppData\Local\Programs\Python, sometimes even both.

My issue is that I have no Python directory in AppData\Local\Programs, and with the command prompt I get this result :

```
C:\Users\redacted> python3 -version
Python est introuvable. Exécutez sans argument pour procéder [insert a few weird characters probably due to an incompatibility in encoding (the "é" were something else as well)]
```

(In English it would probably be something like "Can't find Python. Execute without argument to proceed")

(by the way, executing python3 without argument just opened a microsoft store window to dl python)

The most notable difference I could find is that I work within Anaconda, and I couldn't find another instance of this problem in Anaconda.

Lastly I must add that I have the same problem with multiple similar librairies (that are installed already, i checked several times in my anaconda navigator), but some others work perfectly fine (numpy, matplotlib, selenium...)

As said above, I tried what was suggested in the other stack overflow question, and I also searched on several other links that appeared related to this, i tried adding the path to my anaconda python.exe in my PATH, and rebooted.

I also tried a pip install in spyder and it confirmed that it was already installed and good.

```
pip install pynacl
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl in c:\users\trist\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in c:\users\trist\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pynacl) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\trist\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl) (2.21)
```

Despite all this, for now it seems like nothing changed.

Does anyone know what I could do ?

Edit: After trying some more stuff i ended up checking directly in my anaconda directory if the module was in fact there, because i was beginning to doubt.
And it so happens that i found it, but then when i checked what was inside the directory the files were in a 'nacl' directory, and not 'pynacl'
so in fact, the one thing i needed to do all along was to change

```
import pynacl
```

to

```
import nacl
```