# How to set up pynacl?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a test command for my Discord bot so that it can join voice chat and play a link that I have it set to. Here is my MRE:

```
# test vc join
@bot.command()
async def test_join(ctx):
    url = adhan_media
    guild = ctx.guild
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    try:
        await channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"I can join voice channels!")
        print(f"Successfully joined voice chanel {channel} in {guild}")
        player.play(url)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"Voice chat test unsuccessful.")
        print(f"Could not join voice channel {channel} in {guild} due to the following error: {e}")
    if channel == None:
        await ctx.send(f"You are not in a voice channel!") 
        print(f"Bot did not join voice channel in {guild} due to {ctx.author} not being in voice chat.")
```

I get:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'pynacl' is not defined`

I expected it to join the voice chat and play the url provided but it does not.

Edit: I know that it is required to install , but I now use Py-Cord, and I want to know how to set up PyNaCl with Py-Cord. I also want to know how to actually USE PyNaCl, for Discord voice.

Comment: did you `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]` as was suggested in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77267377/1358308)?  A more complete back trace would help a lot to understand what's going on as the code you includes in the question doesn't include `pynacl`.

Comment: @SamMason yes, and it included pynacl. I think I put the wrong code, as the ai had told me when i searched how to set up the player to put ```pynacl.Player()```, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Might be worth going through some Python tutorials rather than relying on AI tools too much, they tend to get the basics wrong a lot.  The sorts of things that are easy to fix once you get to know the language a bit, but difficult if you're just getting started and get a blob of code that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cant import pynacl module. (discrod.py - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynacl')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222729/i-cant-import-pynacl-module-discrod-py-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named)

Comment: @SecurityHound no i wanted to know how to use it

Comment: So the accepted answer to that question, when you verified your python environment, did not resolve your error? Sounds like you need to provide more of your MRE because something isn’t adding up

Comment: @SecurityHound i stopped using this package because i decided the bot doesn’t need it

Comment: @zoomingspeed - that does not exclude it from being a duplicate.