# Windows 10: Make Py Launcher choose official installation instead of Anaconda (same Python version)

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed official Python then Anaconda3 afterwards (both 3.9)

I suspect it is because I ticked 'Register Anaconda3 as my default Python 3.9' when I was installing Anaconda, that now when I type `py -0p` in `cmd`, the path goes to Anaconda (I do not have Anaconda in `PATH`). I would like Python 3.9 to use the official installation.

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows *
 -3.9-64        C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\python.exe
```

What exactly did ticking 'Register Anaconda3 as my default Python 3.9' change in my system? I would like to revert it. I already looked for `py.ini` and it does not exist beside `py.exe` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, so it is not that.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68121982/multiple-python-versions-installed-how-to-set-the-default-version-for-py-exe help? How about https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customizing-default-python-versions ? "the path goes to Anaconda" What exactly does this mean? Can you show the command output for `py -0p` (redact user names in paths if you wish), formatted as code?

Comment: How about https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/ ?

Comment: @karl-knechtel They do not help, I have seen this, these only choose the versions but do not choose the python path to use for the selected version. I have found the solution though, I will update my question with command output so that others with the same problem can match my question to their issue.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With reference to this comment: [py launcher does not find my Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503003/py-launcher-does-not-find-my-python-2-7#comment79971537_27523478), I deleted `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.9` in `regedit`. `py -0p` gave this output after a reboot, which is what I wanted:

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows *
 -3.9-64        C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
```

**My Python installation is system-wide**, so the keys for the offical installation exist at `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.9`.

For those who installed Python for their user only, you may want to modify the keys in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.9` instead of deleting them.