# How to set default python version for py.exe when multiple versions are installed in windows

Tags: python

I have both 3.10 and 3.11b3 installed on my windows 10 machine. I'd like py.exe to launch 3.10.

I had read that I should create `py.ini` and `pyw.ini` in both `c:\windows` and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\` and the files should contain:

```
[defaults]
python=3.10
```

[Multiple Python versions installed : how to set the default version for py.exe (Python Launcher for Windows) for CMD and for "Open with"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68121982/multiple-python-versions-installed-how-to-set-the-default-version-for-py-exe/68139696)

I set these up after installing 3.11b3, but `py.exe` launches the beta. I don't have any other `py.ini` files. How do I fix this so `c:\windows\py.exe` launches my preferred default version?

Two possible solutions have other issues. I could `set PY_PYTHON=3.10`, but that also changes `python` which is a problem in a `venv`. I could also use `py -3.10`, but I don't understand why the listed solution isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the encoding of your .ini files:  They should be in UTF-8.**

(UTF-8 with BOM doesn't work. Bug reported [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/99620)).

Then follow the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139696/1486850).