# Why the pylauncher default version is not the latest?

Tags: python, windows

I was using python 3.10, but I had to reinstall 3.9 (using python.org installer) to use a package that is not yet 3.10 compatible.

The pylauncher documentation says that, without an explicit version, it runs the "latest version". I realise now how it is ambiguous: latest released or latest installed?

I wrongly was expecting the first. The following command result shows, with the star, that the default version is 3.9.

```py
>> py -0
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64 *
 -3.10-64
```

I didn't find how to set the default to 3.10. Any clue?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See the docs discussion of defaults here https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows, and the related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-default-python-version-in-windows.

Comment: Thank you. I now see that Python doc says it's the last installed version, which is counter intuitive.