# How can I set python3 as python in anaconda in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda

In my anaconda environment in Windows 10,

`python --version` shows `Python 3.7.6`,
and `python3 --version` shows `Python 3.9.12`

How can I set `python` to use `Python 3.9.12` which is used by `python3`?

Because I use Windows, `alias python=python3` command does not work.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913040/5566217

Comment: @PrestonHager The solution is not for anaconda. 'C:\Python39\', which is not used in anaconda, is already top of the list in Path variable.

Comment: Seems like the default is 3.9 [according to the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html). Try doing either `conda update python` or for a specific version: `conda install python=3.9`.

Comment: I tried `conda install python=3.9`, which have updated python3 version to 3.9.
`python --version` is still 3.7.6

Comment: Since the default version is 3.9, try deleting all config files, and your 3.7.6 version of Python if you don't need it. Then reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: I want to switch the python version of the existing anaconda environment, which I have already installed a lot of modules. 
If I need to reinstall anaconda, I could create new anaconda environment with Python 3.9.