# Setting default python Interpreter in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

I have installed python 3.9.13 on my windows `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\` but whenever I tried to open python using command prompt by typing the command `python`it opens another python Interpreter that is python 3.9.11 which is present in `c:\msys64\mingw64\bin` which is basically for C programs. How can I configure my default python Interpreter for all the python files

I tried placing the location of 3.9.13 above the location of 3.9.11 in environment variables but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Should I Set Default Python Version In Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087831/how-should-i-set-default-python-version-in-windows)

Comment: My problem is different as I don't have to select between different Python version a have to assign the original python Interpreter instead of the mingw python Interpreter which is for C programs

Comment: Most of the answers there still apply. For example updating the `PATH` so that the folder which contains Python 3.9.13 comes first. Also for example using the Python Launcher (`py`) instead of `python` directly.